# Can re.findall() return only the part of the regex in parens?

Tags: python, regex

Looping through some data, I want to capture string of numbers that appear as  page IDs (with more than one per line.) However, I only want to match number strings as part of a particular URL, but I DON'T want to record the URL, just the number.

URLs are relative, with digits strings of variable length, of the form

```
/view/123456.htm
```

Data to be returned here would be '123456'

I am currently using re.findall to identify the right URLs, and then re.sub to extract the number strings.

```
views = re.findall(r"/view/\d*?.htm", line)
for view in views:
    view = re.sub(r"/view/(\d+).htm", r"\1", view)
    pagelist.append(view)
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
views = re.findall(r"/view/(\d*?).htm", r"\1", line)   #I know this doesn't work
```

where the original findall() only returns the part of the match in parens?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some sample URLs you want to match and the desired output for each.

Comment: @LutzHorn What exactly is unclear for you?

Comment: @hek2mgl I could *guess* what this question is about. But the quality of this question and of SO as a site would improve if questions would include desired input and output.

Comment: Basically I'm with you, but I don't miss something in this post. It is 100% clear what should being matched, the question is more about how to access match results efficiently in python.

Answer (score 6):

> Can re.findall() return only the part of the regex in parens?

It not only **can**, it **does**:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"/view/(\d*?).htm", "/view/123.htm /view/456.htm")
['123', '456']
```

Did you not try it? [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall) describes it as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [a lookbehind and a lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make findall only return the numbers. For example:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=/view/)\d*?(?=\.htm)", "/view/123.htm /view/456.htm")
['123', '456']
```

These kind of assertions can be used to define what should being before and after a match - without including them into the actual match.

**Update:** Please check [Stefan Pochmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530171/171318), If you are using a single capturing group only, `findall()` will behave exactly as you requested.

Comment: Actually, if there are any groups, returning only a list with their contents *is* what `findall` does.

Comment: @StefanPochmann LOL :D That's funny! Especially since I really read the documentation before posting! I was concerned about multiple capturing groups, but in this case there is just *one*.

Comment: Yeah, and if there were several groups, then hopefully because they're wanted, and then it works as well. Btw, at first I also thought it didn't do it, but probably only because of the question's suggestive power :-)

Comment: `if there were several groups, then hopefully because they're wanted` - good point! Thanks for enlighting us! :)